# How to compile android ndk binder source code

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to compile binder native code which is in c++
i have downloaded native source code for  version 4.04.

when i try to build this library it gives me following errors:

```
    Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-15 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
   [armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libzzz.so
    D:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/zzz/Binder.o: in function android::Vector<android::String16>::do_copy(void*, void const*, unsigned int) const:jni/utils/TypeHelpers.h:142: error: undefined reference to 'android::String16::String16(android::String16 const&)'
    D:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/zzz/Binder.o: in function android::Vector<android::String16>::do_splat(void*, void const*, unsigned int) const:jni/utils/TypeHelpers.h:154: error: undefined reference to 'android::String16::String16(android::String16 const&)'
    D:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/zzz/Binder.o: in function android::Vector<android::String16>::do_destroy(void*, unsigned int) const:jni/utils/TypeHelpers.h:132: error: undefined reference to 'android::String16::~String16()'
```

Android.mk

```
sources := \
Binder.cpp \
BpBinder.cpp \
CursorWindow.cpp \
IInterface.cpp \
IMemory.cpp \
IPCThreadState.cpp \
IPermissionController.cpp \
IServiceManager.cpp \
MemoryDealer.cpp \
MemoryBase.cpp \
MemoryHeapBase.cpp \
MemoryHeapPmem.cpp \
Parcel.cpp \
PermissionCache.cpp \
ProcessState.cpp \
Static.cpp

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread
LOCAL_MODULE := libbinder1
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libcutils libutils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(sources)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

i searched a lot but dint find any help.
any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Can you post your Android.mk file?

Comment: i edited my post..please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**delete your previously generated "obj" file from jni and then add android.mk file like below**

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE    := "your shared library name"// while compile it will be generated as [.so]
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 Binder.cpp \
 BpBinder.cpp \
 CursorWindow.cpp \
 IInterface.cpp \
 IMemory.cpp \
 IPCThreadState.cpp \
 IPermissionController.cpp \
 IServiceManager.cpp \
 MemoryDealer.cpp \
 MemoryBase.cpp \
 MemoryHeapBase.cpp \
 MemoryHeapPmem.cpp \
 Parcel.cpp \
 PermissionCache.cpp \
 ProcessState.cpp \
 Static.cpp


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: jni/IPCThreadState.cpp:292:8: error: 'pthread_mutex_t' does not name a type
generated many errors like this

Comment: i fixed above error by adding LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_PTHREADS but that resulted in huge list of errors at the time of generating .so

Comment: eg  D:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/libliblib/Binder.o: in function android::Vector<android::String16>::do_copy(void*, void const*, unsigned int) const:jni/utils/TypeHelpers.h:142: error: undefined reference to 'android::String16::String16(android::String16 const&)'